# How can I find the domain of a samba server?

Tags: windows, samba, domain, smb

How can I determine the domain of a remote samba server from the command line?

Comment: You've tagged windows; are you running from a windows command line or some unix flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `smbclient -L remote-server` contains the domain; the linked page shows an example:

```
smbclient -L zimmerman
```

The output of this command should look something like this:

```
 Server time is Sat Aug 10 15:58:27 1996
Timezone is UTC+10.0
Password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows NT 3.51] Server=[NT LAN Manager 3.51]

Server=[ZIMMERMAN] User=[] Workgroup=[WORKGROUP] Domain=[]

    Sharename      Type      Comment
    ---------      ----      -------
    ADMIN$         Disk      Remote Admin
    public         Disk      Public 
    C$             Disk      Default share
    IPC$           IPC       Remote IPC
    OReilly        Printer   OReilly
    print$         Disk      Printer Drivers


This machine has a browse list:

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    HOPPER               Samba 1.9.15p8
    KERNIGAN             Samba 1.9.15p8
    LOVELACE             Samba 1.9.15p8
    RITCHIE              Samba 1.9.15p8
    ZIMMERMAN
```

Reference: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html